# Why is jQuery-UI draggable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code and am trying to allow a point (img and text within a div) to be draggable once it is created.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/aoi.png" alt="" />
    <div id="point_panel">
        <form>
            <fieldset id="point_container">
                <img id="point" src="images/point.png" alt="" /><input id="point_name" type="text" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#point').click(function() {
            var alt = $('#point_name').val();
            $('#container').append('<div class="points"><img src="images/point.png" alt=\"'+alt+'\" />'+alt+'</div>');
        });
        $('.points').draggable({ containment: '#container', stack: '.points', opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 100 });
    });
</script>
```

User clicks on the img in the form, a new div with the same img and text is created. That div should then be draggable anywhere within the div with the id of container.

When I create the point, it cannot be dragged. Anything missing from my code?

Thanks

Comment: You are binding the draggable event before your .points element even exists, so the event is not binded to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#point').click(function() {
        var alt = $('#point_name').val();
        var el = $('<div class="points"><img src="images/point.png" alt=\"'+alt+'\" />'+alt+'</div>');
        $('#container').append(el);
        $(el).draggable({ containment: '#container', stack: '.points', opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 100 });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just as an additional note. The reason for setting your "points" HTML to a variable el and issuing the draggable bind to variable el is because this is faster than doing a bind to all ".points" elements. Class selectors in jQuery are powerful but relatively slow, so it's best to avoid them when possible.

Comment: Good to know. I am still relatively new to jquery. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, using class selectors is not *that* big of a deal, but jQuery does have to look through the entire DOM when you use one. It's completely okay to use them, but it's also good to get into the habit of not using them when there is an easy alternative. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#point').click(function() {
                var alt = $('#point_name').val();
                $('#container').append('<div class="points"><img src="images/point.png" alt=\"'+alt+'\" />'+alt+'</div>');
                //bind draggable to last inserted div 
                $('#container').find('.points:last').draggable({ containment: '#container', stack: '.points', opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 100 });            
             });
            $('.points').draggable({ containment: '#container', stack: '.points', opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 100 });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Aymen. roflmao's solution is a bit cleaner so I will go with that one.